# I want to create a new frequency column for each column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

| colors | animals |
| --- | --- |
| yellow | cat |
| yellow | cat |
| red | cat |
| red | cat |
| blue | cat |

I want to create a column for each column showing the frequency in which each value happens:

| colors | colors_frequency | animals | animals_frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yellow | 40% | cat | 100% |
| yellow | 40% | cat | 100% |
| red | 40% | cat | 100% |
| red | 40% | cat | 100% |
| blue | 20% | cat | 100% |

I tried

```
frequency = list()
for column in df.columns:
     series = (df[column].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=True)*100)
     overview.append(series)

#overview list
o_colors = overview[0] 
o_animals = overview[1]

df['animals_frequency'] = o_animals
```

If I try

```
df.info()
```

it returns

| Column | Non-Null | Count | Dtype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| animals_frequency | 0 | non-null | float64 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach is to calculate the relative frequency for each column values and then join these frequencies back to the original DataFrame.

```
for col in df.columns:
    # Get relative frequency
    frequency = df[col].value_counts(normalize=True)

    # Format frequency as percent values, rounded to two decimals
    frequency_percent = (frequency*100).round(2).astype(str) + '%'

    # Join frequency values to original DF
    frequency_percent.name = f"{col}_frequency"
    df = df.merge(frequency_percent.to_frame(), left_on=col, right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

For each column, compute the frequency of each distinct element. Then, use `replace` to map each element to the corresponding frequency

```py
for column in df.columns:
    mapping = df[column].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=True) * 100
    df[f"{column}_frequency"] = df[column].replace(mapping)
```